# Using bash alias beyond one level (shell in shell)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, alias

I am looking to execute a alias on my terminal which will login to another shell and execute a command there.

For example,

sh = 'ssh admin@x.x.x.x'

shls = 'sh;ls' (also tried 'sh && ls')

In this scenario, when i give 'shls', i want to ssh to (pwd less entry enabled) x.x.x.x and then execute ls command over there. But the 'ls' part is not working.

I understand the shell changed and hence its no longer in parent shell's scope to trigger the ls, but just wondering if there is a way to push it to the logged in shell and execute there.

Infact, i wanted to use another alias which is avaiable in x.x.x.x in place of 'ls' but as a first step i want to atleast get this working.

Hope i could put it clearly, Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Questions about interactive use, as opposed to scripting, are a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) rather than StackOverflow. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, our scope is limited to questions *unique to software development*; folks who aren't software developers set up shell aliases.

Comment: `sa() { ssh admin@x.x.x.x "$@"; }; sals() { sa ls "$@"; }`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to post my future queries on interactive use as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a command to `ssh` as an argument (after the various connection parameters):

```
alias shls='ssh admin@x.x.x.x ls'
```

BTW, I'd recommend against aliasing `sh` -- that's a commonly used command to run a shell script(*), and giving it a different meaning could cause confusion.

(* Though instead using the `sh` command, it's generally better to give the script a proper shebang line, and just enter its path.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works very fine for me. However i'm trying to use another alias in place of 'ls' which will take me into a docker shell (docker exec command). Here i'm getting "cannot enable tty mode on non tty input" error. Trying to figure out what might be causing this.

Also, i just quoted 'sh' as example, i was not using the same for alias. Anyways, thanks for the tip.